# how can I now the index of entered character for textArea in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

this is my fxml area

```
    <TextArea fx:id="textArea"  onKeyTyped="#handleTextAreaAction" 
        BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
        </BorderPane.margin>
        <padding>
            <Insets bottom="1.0" left="1.0" right="1.0" top="1.0" />
        </padding>
    </TextArea>
```

and this is my method in the controller:

```
    @FXML private TextArea textArea;
    public void handleTextAreaAction(KeyEvent event) 
    {
     textArea.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

       System.out.println(event.getCode());

        }
    });
}
```

I want to know how I can know the index of each character that user input into the text area

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx getting input from TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219536/javafx-getting-input-from-textfield)

Comment: It's probably better to listen to the `text` property and/or the cursor position...